# detect any combining character in Java

Tags: java, regex, unicode, combining-marks

I am looking for a way to detect if a character in a java string "is a combining character" or not.  For instance,

```
String khmerCombiningVowel = 
 new String(new byte[]{(byte) 0xe1,(byte) 0x9f,(byte) 0x80}, "UTF-8"); // unicode 17c0
```

represents a [combining Khmer vowel sign](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/17c0/index.htm).  I have tried `"\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}"` [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11309788/32453) but it doesn't seem to apply to these particular combining characters.  Or even if there is some comprehensive list of all unicode combining character blocks I might be able to make a regex for them?

Comment: Here is a link to all Unicode Characters in the Combining Diacritical Marks Block: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/combining_diacritical_marks/list.htm

Comment: Yeah oddly, this character appears to be a combining mark, but *outside* the "combining diacriticals" block.  It's like...some other block maybe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Algorithm to check for combining characters in Unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17051732/algorithm-to-check-for-combining-characters-in-unicode), there are a number of blocks for combining characters.

Java has a number of helpful functions, try:

```
String codePointStr = new String(new byte[]{(byte) 0xe1, (byte) 0x9f, (byte) 0x80}, "UTF-8"); // unicode 17c0
System.out.println(codePointStr.matches("\\p{Mc}"));
System.out.println(
    Character.COMBINING_SPACING_MARK == Character.getType(codePointStr.codePointAt(0)));
```

(prints true in both cases)

In this case, the [COMBINING_SPACING_MARK](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#COMBINING_SPACING_MARK) (and related regex `\p{gc=Mc}`) both refer to the [Unicode category](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Mc/list.htm) "Mark, Spacing Combining" which is basically any character that combines with a previous character while also adding width.

Other regular expressions that may be useful: `\p{M}` for [any kind of mark](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html).  If you want to use the Character `getType()` constants, you can get the same behavior to that by checking if its type is `COMBINING_SPACING_MARK` or `ENCLOSING_MARK`, or `NON_SPACING_MARK`.

ENCLOSING_MARK is a surrounding character, like a circle--also adds width to the character it combines with.

[NON_SPACING_MARK](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#NON_SPACING_MARK) includes the Latin alphabet diacritical combining marks, etc. (Marks that basically go on top or below, and don't add any width to the character).