# Different count for String.length() for different languages

Tags: java, android, android-studio

What I want

Given a String s and a coordinate x1, want to print to pdf considering x1 at the center. 
I need starting x-coordinate

problem

I can easily calculate start coordinate(x) with  x1-s.length()/2  to a position it at the center but it fails for Hindi(Language)

How to count the actual no of characters ignoring the Unicode characters but the letters.
[I basically want to print the string at the center, String is variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5jWO.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of reasons why the `length` method might get you an unexpected answer.

The length method on `String` returns the number of char values in the string, but there are more Unicode characters than possible `char` values, so for some characters more than one char value is used to store the character. To get the length you expect for, try this: `s.codePointCount(0, s.length())`

If your string contains a [Combining Diacritical Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_Diacritical_Marks), that uses one char, but is displayed combined with another character. Here's a question about how to spot those: [detect any combining character in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29110887/detect-any-combining-character-in-java#29111105)